# Create Elasticsearch template without mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to create a template to have some common index settings for a single node `Elasticsearch` cluster. When I run the following query, it works fine, however, the new index has empty mapping therefore it rejects all input.

I believe it overrides the index settings and removes all mappings.

```
PUT /_template/logstash
{
  "index_patterns": ["logstash-*"],
  "order" : 0,
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the glimpse of the errors I am getting:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-23T02:06:12,383Z", "level": "DEBUG", "component": "o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch-cluster", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "[logstash-2019.12.23][0] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[logstash-2019.12.23][logevent][oGSBMG8Bk2kiyC1FN2uU], source[{\"@timestamp\":\"2019-12-23T05:04:44.0042561+03:00\",\"level\":\"Information\",\"messageTemplate\":\"HalalahContactService: Mobile Number: 123456789\",\"message\":\"ContactService: Mobile Number: 123456789\",\"fields\":{\"CorrelationId\":\"123456789\",\"MachineName\":\"INTERNAL-API02\"}}]}", "cluster.uuid": "1p7WBSRcQ6iCEJYflcALEQ", "node.id": "5nVSS69WRCiF_v3NsmsCHQ" ,
"stacktrace": ["java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rejecting mapping update to [logstash-2019.12.23] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, logevent]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:238) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:702) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.calculateTaskOutputs(MasterService.java:324) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:219) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.access$000(MasterService.java:73) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:151) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:703) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:215) [elasticsearch-7.5.1.jar:7.5.1]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]"] }
```

Comment: Can you check if you don't have dynamic mapping disabled at index/cluster level?

Comment: You can't put * as index_patterns, because in this way it will conflicts with hidden indices as .kibana .monitoring. Please specify an array of index with wildcards to achieve your purpose

Comment: @Lupanoide I also tried logstash-* to match only specific indexes but the result was the same.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I have a manually installed 7.3.1 single node cluster where the same settings is working but this one 7.5.0 running in docker-compose having issue. I checked in both places mapper.dynamic is set to true.

Comment: Could you also paste error message as well?

Comment: If you remove the `custom` template, do you have the same issue?

Comment: @glenacota, no, without template, it works perfectly fine. I deleted custom template along with the index and it created a new index which receives data with no problem.

Comment: Could you paste the error message when you try to index data with the custom template in place? (as asked by @Evaldas)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I have updated my question with error message. I am sorry for the long delay, I was occupied by something else. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so your error message says it all!

Your custom index template is not really the issue, documents that are being indexed are. Since version 7, Elasticsearch no longer allows multiple types per index, just a single one (`_doc` as a default for now) and later will remove them completely.

So the issue really is that type, other than default, probably `logevent`, is being attempted to be indexed. Make these index type consistent and it'll work.

Comment: Can you please help me understand why it is working when I deleted custom template? The applications are using Serilog by the way.

Comment: This is an educated guess, but I think that multiple applications write into the same index and clash due to different types, so it's probably which application starts first and then the other ones starts throwing up. In your case - I would not use logstash template index and use something from your domain, I suspect Logstash creates its own template and then writes documents into it. I never used Serilog, but I am 100% sure it's possible to specify a custom index (index pattern) to write into - try that.